# How to change the popup size in PysimpleGUI in python?

Tags: python, pip, pysimplegui

I am using PYsimpleGUI in my python code, and while using the popup element how do you resize the popup window?

My code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.popup("Hello!")
```

How to resize sg.popup?

Also, is there an option to add a title to the popup window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no size parameter in `sg.popup`, however you can adjust the size of the window by changing the contents of the text shown, ie. longer string and some empty lines.

Another option would be creating a new pop up funtion that works similar to the `sg.popup` but based on `sg.Window` object. This way you can be more flexible with the parameters.

You can add the title by using the title parameter: `sg.popup('world', title='hello')`

Comment: Title works, and thank for the info. about `sg.popup`, `sg.window` idea also works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To resize while using the element, you can do that by using the Stretch element to push stuff around.

To set the title, it's simple as

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
```

If you are new to the library, the [documentation](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered there is no `size` parameter for the `sg.popup()` function and you can use spaces and empty strings like paddings this way:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# blanks like paddings example
sg.popup("", "          Hello!          \x00", "")
```

the empty strings before and after **Hello!** behave like vertical padding while the spaces inside **Hello!** string behave like horizontal padding.

Now you could ask why the hex escape character `\x00`?

It's the workaround I found, stands for the **Null character** and without it doesn't pad on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the popup scrolled to create a popup with size attributes:

example:

```
sg.popup_scrolled("Qty NOW: 12\nQty Initial: 11\nPN: CamposFields\nStatus: Start", 
                  title="Running checks...", 
                  auto_close=True, 
                  auto_close_duration=10, 
                  size=(30, 10)
                  )
```